# BeautifulSoup removing nested tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a generic scraper using BeautifulSoup for which I am trying to detect the tag under which directly text is available.

Consider this example:

```
<body>
<div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="c3">
            <div class="c4">
                <div class="c5">
                    <h1> A heading for section </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="c5">
                    <p> Some para </p>
                </div>
                <div class="c5">
                    <h2> Sub heading </h2>
                    <p> <span> Blah Blah </span> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here my objective is to extract (div with class c4) as it has all the textual content. Rest of the div before it c1 - c3 are just wrappers for me.

One possible way for identifying the node, I came up is:

```
if node.find(re.compile("^h[1-6]"), recursive=False) is not None:
    return node.parent.parent
```

But it is too specific for this case.

Is there any optimized way for finding text in one level of recursion. i.e. if I do something like

```
node.find(text=True, recursion_level=1)
```

then it should return text considering only immediate children.

My solution so far, not sure if it holds for all cases.

```
def check_for_text(node):
    return node.find(text=True, recursive=False)

def check_1_level_depth(node):
    if check_for_text(node):
        return check_for_text(node)

    return map(check_for_text, node.children)
```

For the code above: node is an element of soup that is currently under check, i.e. div, span, etc.
Please assume that I am handling all exceptions in check_for_text() (AttributeError: 'NavigableString')

Comment: Have you tried using CSS selectors? `soup.select(".c4")`

Comment: I cannot use css selectors. Because the different sites will have different naming.

Comment: Note that [tag:data-mining] refers to complex statistical analysis on large quantities of data. You probably meant [tag:web-scraping], the extraction of text from web pages.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, thanks for referring the correct tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I have to write a recursive function to eliminate the tags with a single child. Here is the code:

```
# Pass soup.body in following
def process_node(node):
    if type(node) == bs4.element.NavigableString:
        return node.text
    else:
        if len(node.contents) == 1:
            return process_node(node.contents[0])
        elif len(node.contents) > 1:
            return map(process_node, node.children)
```

So far it is working good and fast.

Comment: use  `if isinstance(node, bs4.element.NavigableString):` instead of `if type(node) == bs4.element.NavigableString:`

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is something like this:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
all = bs.findAll()

previous_elements = []
found_element = None

for i in all:
    if not i.string:
        previous_elements.append(i)
    else:
        found_element = i
        break

print("previous:")
for i in previous_elements:
    print(i.attrs)

print("found:")
print(found_element)
```

output:

```
previous:
{}
{'class': ['c1']}
{'class': ['c2']}
{'class': ['c3']}
{'class': ['c4']}
found:
<h1> A heading for section </h1>
```

Comment: There may be multiple 'div's unlike the example shown. Also after finding the element with string I should return the parent of the element right?

Comment: then you can repeat the same job for all the divs

Comment: instead of doing a break on c5, save it and continue

Comment: How about a DFS on the parse tree?

Comment: if you continue the loop instead of break it will be DFS

Comment: the `found_element` has a `parent` attribute. as long as its found, when looping you can compare the `found.parent` with `current.parent`, if its the same skip, so you can find the next div.not sure if beautiful soup can give you a tree

Comment: this is the easiest solution i could come up with, if you have them in a tree strucutre you could say give me the next node, well you have to search the doc if it provides a tree.

Comment: actualy `if found.parent not in current.parents` instead of `parent`

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to be finding the Common Ancestors for found elements at lowest element. Let me check if that works.