# How to get the text in a particular div avoiding the text from nested divs via BS4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

the structure looks like this

```html
<div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  98
</div>
```

How to get only **`'98'`** ignoring the text in other nested divs via BeautifulSoup

piece of code:

```html
<div class="b-stickiness js-stickiness">
 <div class="b-stickiness__ico">
  <svg class="sc-icon" data-group="xs" data-name="ChartPie" fill="currentColor" height="12" preserveaspectratio="xMidYMid meet" viewbox="0 0 12 12" width="12">
   <path d="M6 1v5h5c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5zm-1 1c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5s2.239 5 5 5 5-2.239 5-5h-5v-5z" shape-rendering="geometricPresision">
   </path>
  </svg>
  <div class="b-stickiness__tooltip js-tooltip">
   <div class="b-stickiness__tooltip__inner">
    <div class="b-stickiness__tooltip__title">
     Wow-Score
    </div>
    <div class="b-stickiness__tooltip__text">
     The Wow-Score shows how engaging a blog post is. It is calculated based on the correlation between users’ active reading time, their scrolling speed and the article’s length.
    </div>
    <a class="b-stickiness__tooltip__btn js-stickiness-btn" data-type="min" href="/wow-score/about/" title="Learn more">
     Learn more
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 99
</div>
```

I want to get that 99

Comment: Try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324530/beautifulsoup-removing-nested-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findAll()` then these arguments:

`string=True` - Search for strings only. [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument)
`recursive=False` - Don't look into the children. [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<div><div>some text</div><div>some text</div>98</div>", "html.parser")

soup.div.findAll(string=True, recursive=False)[-1]

>>> '98'
```

Comment: mate, it's definitely thats what I need but I cant get why it isnt working with my code. I've added it to my question, please help

Comment: thanks! the problem was that there is a space in a code higher so I was getting space as a result. the full decision for my code looks like this:

number = social.div.findAll(string=True, recursive=False)[1].replace('\n','')

Answer (score 1):

*Try using `div:nth-child(2)` to get the next `div` with **[.next_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)** to navigate between elements*

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
  <div>some text 1</div>
  <div>some text 2</div>
  98
</div>
"""

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(page_soup.select("div:nth-child(2)")[0].next_sibling)
```

---

*Prints out **`98`***